# Matrix mechanics is enough?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Is it possible to formulate and get all the results of quantum mechanics using Matrix mechanics only? without the wave function?
Especially I want to know whether matrix elements such as the dipole moment:  can be calculated without the Schrodinger's wave function.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix formulation of quantum mechanics is completely equivalent to Schrödinger's wave function formulation of quantum mechanics. This has already been shown by Schrödinger himself and expanded by Dirac and by von Neumann.This means that also the dipole moment can be obtained by both versions of quantum mechanics. There is, however, a considerable difference in the computational ease to obtain certain results. Very often the Schrödinger wave function approach is easier to handle.  I have not done it myself, but I suspect that it is also easier to calculate the dipole moment via the wave function approach.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to calculate the dipole moment using matrix mechanics only?

Comment: @Jacob - Sorry, I was looking, but couldn't find any example for a calculation of the dipole moment using matrix mechanics.